# Why is nothing happening to a flagged question?

Tags: support, questions, flags, vote-to-close, moderation

A couple of days ago there was a question about show/hide in javascript: [Show\Hide html element - pros and cons to each approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536252/show-hide-html-element-pros-and-cons-to-each-approach)

This was not my question, but it was one that I tried to answer. It was put on hold due to being "opinion-based". Now while I disagree with the original claim that it was opinion-based, I decided to fix the problem by editing the original question. The edit was approved and I flagged the question to have it re-reviewed, but nothing has been done.

If this edit isn't good enough, why is it not being added to the comments as to why? I don't know a lot about stackoverflow other than getting info from it, but it appears that no one has been notified to review it, or it is being wrongfully ignored.

Since then I have completely revamped my original answer and gave a really useful answer to any future user who stumbles upon it, but if this isn't reopened it will be closed (at least as far as I understand the process).

Comment: Asking for pros and cons is still asking for opinions, no?

Comment: What do you mean? They are facts, not opinions. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: It depends on what you are asking for pros and cons *for* but what one person sees as a pro, another might see as a con. Also, the usage of each hugely depends on the situation and other code in the vicinity that may impact the decision on which approach to use.

Comment: I don't agree with the pro/con thing. I mean obviously some things suffer from that, but it isn't everything unless one is trying to be absurd. For instance, if we were talking about processors and I compared a Pentium III vs any modern processor and I said that a pro to the modern one was that it is faster, it is absurd to call that an opinion. If you look at my answer I even demonstrate the pro/con without opinions by simply saying when one thing is positive and when it is negative, thereby making it a fact. I don't know what else you can call it except anti-flaw/flaw or fact/negative fact.

Comment: You're right, it's not opinion-based. "Too broad" would have been a more appropriate choice. Should we re-open and re-close it?

Comment: I suppose you can call it "too broad", but there are a finite and small number of reasonable ways to show/hide so I don't agree that it is broad. Using that mentality, many legitimate questions would be closed. Here is my question for you, do you think that the information from my answer would be helpful for future users or hurtful?

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is an anomaly. Look at the other answers on that question. Imagine how many more we'd attract if the question had remained open. This is why this type of question is a problem.

Comment: That question is almost the textbook definition of "too broad" PoB works aswell, imo.

Comment: For what it's worth: even though "Too broad" may be more suitable, I don't see the point in re-opening and then closing it again.

Comment: He was joking about doing that.

Comment: I don't think he was. Sometimes, that does happen on purpose when questions are closed for a completely irrelevant reason.

Comment: Ah ok, I can see that, but why not instead make an effort to resolve the issues with the question so that it can still stand. @CodyGray As for the other answers, these were given prior to the edit of the question and to base the decision to not reopen it on that, I find to be the same as not allowing questions to be answered in general because they could have bad answers. That is what downvoting is for right?

Comment: The question would still be a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is ***too broad***, it's a ***duplicate*** of numerous "Hide / show" question, and it's still asking *"What's the best method"*, which is ***opinion based***, even though you disguised it as *"What are the pros / cons"*.

Personally, I'd have marked it as a dupe of:
[javascript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element), but the *"Too broad"* or *"Opinion based"* closure reasons apply as well.

The reason the question wasn't re-opened when you flagged it, was because it shouldn't be.

Comment: Tell me then, what is the proper way to ask for a comparison between multiple methods so that a user can compare them and choose the most suitable one? I will edit it to be that instead. Whatever the way is, I think that what I wrote was far more valuable than the information that was in the one you are calling a duplication and I would like future users to benefit from choice and understanding rather than copy-paste-pray.

Comment: @Macainian I think questions of that nature are just not good for stack overflow.

Comment: You realize that you just gave an opinion to a topic about how opinions are bad...

Comment: @Macainian well, it is the opinion of the community that opinion questions are bad - but it's an opinion fed by years of experience

Comment: @Macainian: Meta is different than SO. Here, it's possible to have a bit of discussion about mainsite issues. That said, even if the question is somehow edited so that's it's impossible to answer it with an opinion, it's still a duplicate.

Comment: @Macainian The reason we have "Primarily opinion based" as a close reason is because these kinds of questions are considered not a good fit for Stackoverflow. Thats not my opinion. Thats community consensus and has been for a long while now.

Comment: Ok fine. I will stop bothering to save it. It seems that it is more important to keep an original question about a topic than one that is bringing more and better information to the table. I am not sure why duplicates are a problem if they are better than the original. Perhaps stackoverflow should start making some wiki pages in addition to q/a so that strong answers can stand without fear of being on a duplicate question and being lost.

Comment: Instead of answering the duplicate, you could also answer the original with the new (, better?) answer. That keeps the relevant information in _one_ place, which helps future visitors.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and take a look at that question. It wouldn't fit. In fact, you would see that it is far from a duplicate at all, but I don't want to argue that. I thought about putting it there, but basically nothing that I put really makes sense there. I would have to say "here is a solution to your specific question, and here is also some information on the various ways you can do show/hide". It would be downvoted to oblivion because it sounds out of place and irrelevant. If I could put it there without basically removing the whole concept, I would.

Comment: There I gave it a shot. I did like you said and I put a reasonable response that included all the information from my post in the other question. I just hope it isn't destroyed and is received well. I think it should be alright, but you never know here on stackoverflow.

Comment: One last thing, why is it that people insist on downvoting this question? I am guessing it is because it is complaint oriented, but it could be found to be useful to a future user facing similar issues. I think people downvote too often based on social reasons rather than logical reasons. I mean I am respectful and I upvoted and selected this answer as the solution, because it is. I could have done as most would by downvoting this answer and not accepting it. This community really needs to get a hold of itself on voting. I am all for downvotes, but base it off of usefulness.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because questions like this one aren't uncommon, and people disagree with re-opening the linked question. But that's just my guess... That said, the attitude you're showing here about downvotes, _"trolls"_, and SO's population isn't really working in your favor, either.

Comment: Disagreeing with re-opening is not really what the voting system is for though. As for the questions like these, although I didn't search thoroughly, I didn't really see others that were quite the same.

Comment: As I mentioned, [voting on meta is different](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @Cerbrus Removed it. Sometimes aggravation takes over in these situations.

Comment: [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: @Macainian I did a few edits myself. You can see the details when you click the edited by link at the bottom. See if you agree with it, if you don't you can roll it back.

Comment: Sounds good. I left a comment on the answer for you.

Comment: @Cerbrus So now my question is, since I have already received so many downvotes, should I just delete this post?

Comment: You shouldn't. People disagreeing with the question doesn't necessarily make it a bad question.

Answer (score 4):

To the simpler question: why have no moderators acted on your flag? Well, because we haven't gotten to it yet. It was cast two days ago in the middle of 205 other custom flags. I tend to triage these flags to act on the most urgent / easiest to judge flags first (someone threatening other users, accusations of plagiarism, sock puppetry, etc.) and leave harder to act on ones for later.

This is a difficult flag for us to handle, because you're asking a single moderator to override the decision of five community members. We're going to need a pretty good, pretty obvious reason to do so.

That's not entirely clear here, so my next step would be to check how the community reviewed the question after your edits. In [a unanimous decision](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/11356676), these reviewers voted to leave the question closed after your edits.

Now I'd be overriding the decision of *eight* community members if I was to reopen this. I'll let others take a look at this flag, but my tendency would be to defer to the community and decline this. Moderators are exception handlers, and I don't see an exceptional enough circumstance here to go against the community votes.

Comment: Yes I agree. After several comments on @Cerbrus's answer, I was able to better understand the reasoning behind and difficulties in fixing this issue. Thank you for your response.